# MVP Supervising Controller, Data Bindings and Undo/Redo

Tags: winforms, data-binding, mvp, undo, undo-redo

My application is a MDI Winform application.
I encounter some problems  connected with MVP pattern and Data Bindings.

All my forms are modeless. When I modify a field, or change the selected item in a combobox, I want to modify the model and I want  all the form (s) to synchronize immediately with the model.
Databinding allow this perfectly for simple fields ,and for complex operations , I use the Presenter to update view "manually" .

But, How to put Undo/redo mechanisms in the picture ?
I mean: I want to revert change I made in a text field by clicking an "undo" button.

I try to apply command pattern, but it seems there is no place to introduce a "command" mechanism in the databinding mechanism. I'm so stuck with this , that I now take under consideration to abandon Binding mechanisms completely.

I see so many articles about Binding, but  no solution to undo/redo is really exposed.

Are undo/redo and databinding really uncompatible?

Comment: Maybe this might help you http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2009/03/20/the-undo-redo-paradox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like the Monitored Undo Framework ( http://muf.codeplex.com/ or on NuGet) to manage the undo stack. It doesn't require the Command pattern. Instead, you monitor changes to your model and then push those changes into the undo stack. Undo a change means pulling the prior value from the stack and pushing it back into the model.

The library was written for WPF, but if you have your bindings setup properly, it should also work for WinForms. Additionally, you can hook callbacks in the model so that you know when a value has changed due to an undo / redo operation.

The library has documentation, unit tests, and links to some samples showing how to use it.